# ¿Puedo usar código Java dentro de la anotación @Calculation en OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

¿La anotación @Calculation soporta código Java? Por ejemplo, ¿el siguiente código funcionaría?

```
LocalDate fechaInicio;

@Calculation("fechaInicio.plusDays(400)")
LocalDate fechaFin;
```

En caso contrario, ¿cómo implementaría este caso?

Answer (score 1):

En @Calculation sólo puedes usar expresiones aritméticas básicas. Si quieres usar Java, crea una propiedad calculada, es decir, simplemente define un getter sin campo y sin setter, de esta forma:

```
@Depends("fechaInicio")
public LocalDate getFechaFin() {
    return fechaInicio.plusDay(400);
}
```

Fíjate en el @Depends("fechaInicio") para que fechaFin se recalcule en la interfaz de usuario cuando fechaInicio cambie.